# What does :0 mean in vnc configuration?

Tags: vnc, display

When I configured VNC server there were strings

```
VNCSERVERS="1:oracle"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 800x600"
```

When I connected via VNC and run `w` command, I saw that current display is :1.

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ w
 06:53:24 up 11 days, 22:15,  2 users,  load average: 0.38, 0.16, 0.10
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/1    win-73viuifj4th  06:39   23.00s  0.04s  0.04s -bash
oracle   pts/2    :1.0             09Sep15  0.00s  0.01s  0.00s w
```

I can't get the display meaning. :0 mean that this is physical display of the current machine, but what :1 and :2 mean?

Comment: `:0 mean that this is physical display` ... not necessarily. It's simply the X session started with `DISPLAY` set to `:0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:0`. `:1`, `:2` all are display nembers (also display names for a single motinor on the same host). If multiple X servers are running on the host then their displays are numbered as incremental values like `:X` starting from `:0` to uniqely identify each one.

Quoting the `DISPLAY NAMES` section from `man 7 X` :

> Display Names
>
> From the user's perspective, every X server has a display name of the
>   form:
>
> hostname:displaynumber.screennumber
>
> This information is used by the application to determine how it should
>   connect to the server and which screen it should use by default (on
>   displays with multiple monitors):
>
> hostname
>
> The hostname specifies the name of the machine to which the display 
>   isphysically connected. If the hostname is not given, the
>   most efficient way of communicating to a server on the same machine
>   will be used.
>
> displaynumber
>
> The phrase "display" is usually used to refer to collection of 
>   monitors that share a common keyboard and pointer (mouse, tablet,
>   etc.). Most workstations tend to only have one keyboard, and
>   therefore, only one display. Larger, multi-user systems, however,
>   frequently have several displays so that more than one person can be
>   doing graphics work at once. To avoid confusion, each display on a
>   machine is assigned a display number (beginning at 0) when the X
>   server for that display is started. The display number must always be
>   given in a display name.
>
> screennumber
>
> Some displays share a single keyboard and pointer among two or 
>   more monitors. Since each monitor has its own set of windows, each
>   screen is assigned a screen number (beginning at 0) when the X server
>   for that display is started. If the screen number is not given, screen
>   0 will be used.

Comment: Does it mean that if I'll plug one more display to my computer, I can connect to computer with :0 screen or :1 and control both screen?

Comment: @kozlone if another screen is added under the same xserver you can access the first one as `:0.0` & the second one as `:0.1`.. if the are on different xservers then the first one would be `:0.0` or simply `:0` & the second one wound be `:1.0` or simply `:1`

Comment: Now I get it :-)